numpy.intersect1d() doesn't detect all intersecting elements
I got the following two arrays for which I want to find all intersecting elements and the corresponding indexes.
To achieve this I used numpy.intersect1d(). However when I apply this I get the following result:
array1 = np.array([1.1, 1.5, 3.5, 6.5, 10, 15, 35, 65, 100, 150, 350, 650, 1000, 1500, 3500]) * 10**-4

array2 = np.array([6.5, 10, 15, 35, 65, 100, 150, 350, 650, 1000, 1500, 3500, 6500, 10000, 15000, 35000, 65000]) * 10**-5 

intersected, i_1, i_2 = np.intersect1d(array1, array2, return_indices=True)

With intersected as:
>>> intersected
[1.5e-04 6.5e-04 1.0e-03 1.5e-03 3.5e-03 6.5e-03 1.0e-02 1.5e-02 3.5e-02
 6.5e-02 1.0e-01 3.5e-01]

For some reason it's missing the elements 3.5e-04 and 1.5e-01.
The same happens when I use a different approach:
>>> np.array(list(set(array1) & set(array2)))
[3.5e-02 1.0e-01 6.5e-02 3.5e-01 1.5e-02 6.5e-04 1.5e-04 1.0e-02 6.5e-03
 3.5e-03 1.5e-03 1.0e-03]

Why is this happening?

Hi, this is related to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Thanks for your guidance. Now that I know the roots of this problem I finally managed to fix it by applying np.round() to my arrays.

You can also play a bit with types of data in the arrays. For example when applying intersection array1 = array1.astype(np.float64) will have different  results to array1 = array1.astype(np.float32). But when rounding is possible I think it is more recommended.
